# Embedding SMPTE timecode into mpeg1/2 video (no audio)

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg, mpeg

I am working on a task which a client requires smpte drop frame timecode to be embedded into an mpeg1/2 video that my software will capture and encode.  I have had success with encoding using both openCV and ffmpeg (windows).  What I am having trouble with is embedding timecode.

I've spent about a month researching this and have not been able to come up with a solution.
Is there software available that can do what I need?

In my head, I picture a video file without timecode and I open with a player. It displays time in hh:mm:ss:ms.  Then I imagine a video with timecode would display time information as hh:mm:ss:ff.  This is not the case. Many video players don't even support displaying timecode.

How is timecode stored in mpeg1/2 files?  I had thought it was stored on a per frame basis and would be as simple as:

```
frameToEncode->setTimecode(SMPTE_DROPFRAME, framenum);
MPEGEncoder::encodeFrame(frameToEncode);
```

I have scoured the internet for an answer to this.  Maybe I'm searching with the wrong terms, but I cannot find a clear cut solution to simply embed timecode to my video file.

I have tried to use ffmpeg for this but have not been able to confirm/deny my attempts.  Is there software I can use that will tell me I have embedded timecode in my video file?  I have tried using adobe premiere pro and roxio creator pro with no success.

Lastly, is what my client asking even possible?  Is it possible to embed timecode.  I am stunned by the lack of information I have been able to find on this and am beginning to think what is required isn't even possible.  If it is possible, is there a commercial or free sdk/library capable of this?

**TL;DR: I need to embed timecode into an mpeg1/2 video file which I am capturing and encoding on the fly.  How is timecode stored in mpeg1/2 files? As a global header? Per frame? Something else? I need software that can verify embedded timecode exists. Is what the client asking even possible? If so, is there a commercial or free SDK available that can accomplish my task?**

Note: I would need a c/c++ library capable of embedding the timecode.